# Why jpeg image becomes 2D array after being loaded

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I have a jpeg image as follows:

[image]

Now I want to load this image to do image processing. I use the following code:

```
from scipy import misc
import numpy as np
im = misc.imread('logo.jpg')
```

Because the image is a coloured one, I would expect `im` is a 3D matrix. However, `im.shape` gives me a 2D matrix:
`(150, 150)`

I tried another way of loading image as follows:

```
from PIL import Image
jpgfile = Image.open("logo.jpg")
```

But `jpgfile` also has the size of `150x150`. 
My question is: What's wrong with my code, or my understanding about RGB image is wrong?
Thank you very much.

Comment: What are the contents of that 2D array ?

Comment: Your understanding of RGB is perfect, this sounds fishy. Note that `scipy.misc` uses PIL, so you tested only one version. The problem might be the JPG format. Have you tried converting to a png first?

Comment: @Rockybilly: It is a 2D array: array([[27, 127, 127, ..., 127, 127, 127],...,[...]],dtype=uint8)

Comment: Why did you post a png image, when you are talking about problems with a jpg one. Maybe just add the correct example-image?

Comment: @sascha that's an upload to the Stack Overflow imgur account; doesn't that convert everything to png automatically?

Comment: @lenhhoxung the [scipy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html#scipy.misc.imread) specify that PIL is used under the hood, but doesn't specify the default `mode` used for reading. So I suggest explicitly passing `RGB` or `RGBA` (in case that applies) when calling `misc.imread`.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: I didn't know scipy.misc uses PIL, thank you for your info. Yes, The original format is png, and it gives the same result.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Even if, it looks like a png was uploaded (according to the file-name; which is clearly suboptimal). It's also quite bad to prepare images for debugging to some site where reencodings can appear.

Comment: @sascha you might have missed my point. I believe that if you upload an image yourself using the editor of SO, it will be uploaded as a png whether you like it or not. And that is the only accepted way of adding images to questions on SO. You are welcome to try this, though; I didn't test it myself now.

Comment: @AndrasDeak If all jpg's would be converted to png's than this is the dumbest concept of all time. Maybe it's that way. I don't know. Even if it would be: then posting am link to some unprocessed source is always better.

Comment: **Just checked the linked image:** no problem with: skimage. Sadly i can't tell you for the moment which plugin was used for reading.

Comment: @sascha I tried it and you're right, it keeps jpg as jpg. I have no idea where I got my original idea from. Thanks.

Comment: I uploaded the jpeg file again, sorry for confusing you, there is no difference in the result.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I'm pretty sure every png over 1mb is made into a jpeg, which does make more sense but will also be problematic for some SO-questions.

Comment: **Update:** Both (jpg and png) are working for me inside scipy and skimage. JPEG: ```(250, 250, 3)```
 PNG: ```(150, 150, 4)```. Show your versions of the libs in use.

Comment: @sascha: My version of scipy is `0.13.0b1`

Comment: @lenhhoxung I knew it, as seen in my comment under Brians answer. Use a current version! You are probably using python-xy on windows; delete it. Use anaconda, if you are on windows (it's also available on Linux and Mac OSX).

Answer (score -1):

From the docs here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html, specify `mode='RGB'` to get the red, green, blue values. The output appears to default to conversion to a grayscale number.

Comment: Where does it say that on that page? I'm honestly curious, I couldn't find it after multiple reads (also, you have a typo, "grays Cale")

Comment: It throws the error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2215, in open
    raise ValueError("bad mode %r" % mode)
ValueError: bad mode 'RGB'`

Comment: @lenhhoxung Then you are using some very old scipy version. Update it and all pain will go away. The question is: why such an old version? Are you by any chance using python-xy on windows?

Comment: I'm also sceptic in regards to ```It defaults to conversion to a grayscale number.``` This is just wrong and works differently for the current scipy version.

Comment: No, I'm using Mac OS X, Sierra (10.12). The library comes with the OS

Comment: @lenhhoxung Than proceed as needed on your OS. But updating scipy will be the best thing to do. If you don't want to do it. Read it in manually with pillow, imageio or freeimage.